# PHP: preg_match length limit

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I use `preg_match('/[a-z]+[0-9]/', strtolower($_POST['value']))` for check that the string contains both letters and numbers. How can I change so it just allow 5 ~ 15 characters?

`/[a-z]+[0-9]{5,15}/` doesn't work.

**UPDATE**
Now I tried:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{5,15}$/', strtolower($_POST['value']))) {
    echo 'Valid!';
}

else {
    echo 'NOOOOO!!!';
}
```

If I type "dfgdfgdfg" in the input field it will say "Valid!". The value has to have both letters and numbers, and between 5-15 characters.

Comment: 5-15 characters? You mean numbers?

Comment: I hope this isn't for imposing a password "strength" ...

Comment: add some examples of correct strings and incorrect

Comment: 5-15 characters together, both numbers and letters. No, it's for the username.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The trick is to use a positive lookahead, well in this case you'll need two.

So `(?=.*[0-9])` will check if there is at least a digit in your input. What's next? You guessed it, we'll just add `(?=.*[a-z])`. Now let's merge it with [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225)'s answer:

```
(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])^[a-z0-9]{5,15}$
```

What does this mean in general?

- `(?=.*[0-9])` : check if there is a digit
- `(?=.*[a-z])` : check if there is a letter
- `^` : match begin of string
- `[a-z0-9]{5,15}` : match digits & letters 5 to 15 times
- `$` : match end of string

From the PHP point of view, you should always check if a variable is set:

```
$input = isset($_POST['value']) ? strtolower($_POST['value']) : ''; // Check if $_POST['value'] is set, otherwise assign empty string to $input

if(preg_match('~(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])^[a-z0-9]{5,15}$~', $input)){
    echo 'Valid!';
}else{
    echo 'NOOOOO!!!';
}
```

<kbd>[**Online regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pN0uJ2/1)</kbd>

Comment: why should I check if variable is set?

Comment: @peeter because you can never trust what the client sends or doesn't send.

Answer (score 9):

Use line start and line end anchors with correct character class in your regex:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{5,15}$/', strtolower($_POST['value']));
```

Your regex: `/[a-z]+[0-9]/` will actually match 1 or more English letters and then a single digit.

Comment: Sorry I had to go for some work and couldn't attend your edited question though glad that you got a good answer from @HamZa

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<?php

 $str = your string here

 preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{5,15}$/', $str);

?>
```

Comment: Please never post "try this" answers on Stack Overflow.